# Font color issue in 256 color vim colorscheme in terminal

Tags: vim, console

Machine Info: Gentoo amd64 + `bash`

I've already  tried to `export` the environment variable `TERM` to `xterm-256color` or `screen-256color`, and `tput colors` also returns `256`. It looks like my terminal can support 256 colors.

I use vim with my favorite colorschema "jellybean" in 256color formatted. When I use the console on local machine, the font color appears really strangely like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/klspl4ayeyraxwb/2013-03-23%2021.43.04.jpg
 ( Sorry post via url, I need 10 reputation to post image... )

But if I use my Macbook OSX terminal or putty on Windows to ssh back to my machine, the font color on vim works fine like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmo4nfrj1ggdb7a/2013-03-23%2021.43.25.jpg

Does anyone else have this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `TERM` is set in your terminal emulator's preferences but you neglected to say what terminal emulator you are using. Oh… are you using the tty console? It doesn't support 256 colors at all.

Comment: do you mean the tty? when system is up and I type my username and password to login, I just export the TERM, and start to vim. I don't know what is my terminal... It is just default console I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a 256 colors colorscheme on the linux console because it simply doesn't support 256 colors.

It's limited to 8 basic colors + 8 "bright" versions of the 8 basics. If you *really* want to use the tty console, you'll need to use a more limited colorscheme adapted to 8/16 colors terminals.

Comment: Thanks! So... if I wanna use 256 colorschema on my local machine, is it right that I install another terminal emulator to use it?

Comment: You'll need to install a desktop environment if you don't already have it, or at least X. I'm not familiar with Gentoo so I can't really help further but it certainly comes with a package manager that you can use to install KDE or Gnome or whatever DE.

Comment: OK! I am installing the gnome now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're running directly in the [Linux console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console). That one runs in a direct (VGA) video mode, and usually supports only 8 colors.

Hard-coding `TERM` does not help here, and is generally not recommended; the value should be provided by your terminal emulator (should you decide to use one). With the correct value for the Linux console, `tput` also has a different result:

```
$ TERM=linux tput colors
8
```

Comment: thx for your explanation. And is it possible to run another console with 256 color support without X environment on Linux??

Comment: Though theoretically possible in certain video modes, I'm not aware that such a high-color console exists. Use X and a terminal emulator like `xterm`.